# Amplitude and frequency of a wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction, acoustics

What is the amplitude and frequency of wave with the following wave equation:
$$y = A \sin^2(2(kx - \omega t))$$

I plotted the wave at $t = 0$. The resulting wave has amplitude $A$. But my textbook gives the answer as $A/2$.

Comment: I suspect your textbook is giving the average amplitude i.e. the average value of $\sin^2x$ is $\tfrac12$.

Comment: Or maybe it means the wave has an amplitude of $A/2$ about it's average value i.e. $\sin^2(x) = \tfrac12 - \tfrac12\cos(2x)$

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude of a function is defined as half of the difference between its maximum and minimum values. This means that even though the maximum value of the function is $1$, the amplitude is calculated as

$$ \frac{1 - 0}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \tag{1}$$

where $0$ is the minimum of your function. In the case of the function $2 \cos \left( x \right)$, the maximum value is $2$, and the minimum is $-2$, so the amplitude would be

$$\frac{2 - \left( -2 \right)}{2} = 2 \tag{2} $$

Although the maximum value is $2$, the amplitude remains $2$ because it is half of the difference between the maximum and minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

Actually

$$\sin \left( 2 x \right) = \frac{1 - \cos \left( 2x \right)}{2} \tag{1} $$

That's how you will make the graph easily and the amplitude will be $A/2$.

Comment: Please use [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write equations here.  Without the exponents, your equation is incorrect.